# what is a indentically labeled series objects in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, series

I wrote:

```
import pandas as pd


df_name=pd.DataFrame({'CODE':['01','02','03','04'],
'NAME':['MICK','DAVID','JEAN','CHERRY']})

df_exp=pd.DataFrame({'TEST':['POST1','POST2','POST3','POST4','POST5','POST6','POST7', 'POST8'],
'PERS CODE':['02','03','01','04','01','02','02','03']})

print(df_name)
print(df_exp)

df_output=pd.DataFrame()
df_output['POST']=df_exp['TEST']
df_output['AGENT']=df_name['NAME'].where(df_name['CODE']==df_exp['PERS CODE'])

print (df_output)
```

it return an error message :ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
I don't understand why...

Answer (score 0):

This means that your two Series have a different index and cannot be compared with `==` (this would work if the index **and** the size were identical).

Use [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) instead:

```
df_name['CODE'].eq(df_exp['PERS CODE'])
```

In context:

```
df_output['AGENT'] = df_name['NAME'].where(df_name['CODE'].eq(df_exp['PERS CODE']))
```

output:

```
    POST   AGENT
0  POST1     NaN
1  POST2     NaN
2  POST3     NaN
3  POST4  CHERRY  # in order of the Series indices, only POST4 matches
4  POST5     NaN
5  POST6     NaN
6  POST7     NaN
7  POST8     NaN
```

However, I suspect this is not what you want and would rather like to [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the names:

```
df_output['AGENT'] = df_exp['PERS CODE'].map(df_name.set_index('CODE')['NAME'])
```

output:

```
    POST   AGENT
0  POST1   DAVID
1  POST2    JEAN
2  POST3    MICK
3  POST4  CHERRY
4  POST5    MICK
5  POST6   DAVID
6  POST7   DAVID
7  POST8    JEAN
```